# Populating the dropdownlistfor using the model

Tags: c#, html, html.dropdownlistfor, dropdownlistfor

first of all, I'm new to the forum. Thanks already for your help.
My problem is populating the dropdownlistfor using the model. I succeeded for one, but when I want to use dropdownlistfor in the second line, the same item is selected as in the first line, even though the data from the model is different. can you help me what is the problem?
below are the dropdownlistfor codes i used

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-9">
                                                                @Html.DropDownListFor(i => i.EducationModel.Assnlicence_Name, Model.University, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-9">
                                                                @Html.DropDownListFor(i => i.EducationModel.Assnlicence_Department, Model.Department, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                            </div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-9">
                                                                @Html.DropDownListFor(i => i.EducationModel.licence_Name, Model.University, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-9">
                                                                @Html.DropDownListFor(i => i.EducationModel.licence_Department, Model.Department, new { @class = "form-control" })
                                                            </div>
```

this will be a profile update page. so the user's data should be selected in the dropdownlistfor while the page is loading. If AssnLicence_Name or AssnLicence_Department is full, even if License_Name and License_Department are empty, AssnLicence_Name and AssnLicence_Department are selected automatically. I checked my model in debug and I'm pretty sure either License_Name or License_Department is empty.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.